# Reorder string contents delimited by semicolon using Regex?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a string of names separated by a semicolon delimiter in the format firstname lastname.

i.e.

```
John Doe; R.J. Smith; Peter T. Thompson; Sabine Geiß
```

How would one reorder these names as 'lastname, firstname', preferably using RegEx?

```
Doe, John; Smith, R.J.; Thompson, Peter T.; Geiß, Sabine
```

Comment: Sorry, I am more familiar with Python but could accommodate php or others.

Comment: It's not easy to know what a "last name" is, in general. (Try Spanish names, for example). http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no suffixes are present (*i.e.* last names are always only the last word), you'd (globally) replace

```
\s*([^\s;]+(?:\s+[^\s;]+)*)\s+([^\s;]+)\s*(?:;|$)
```

with

```
$2, $1
```

Comment: This won't work for the last name in the string, because it's not followed by `;`.

Answer (score 2):

The regex would be:

```
/\s?([\w.\s]+)\s([\w.]+);/g
```

This will match first and second word, followed by `;`.

To achieve what you want in (for example) JavaScript:

```
your_string.replace(/\s?([\w.\s]+)\s([\w.]+);/g, "$2, $1")
```

Example:

```
"John Doe; R.J. Smith; Peter T. Thompson; Sabine Geiß".replace(/\s?([\w.\s]+)\s([\w.]+);/g, " $2, $1;")
" Doe, John; Smith, R.J.; Thompson, Peter T.; Sabine Geiß"
```

Comment: It didn't flip the last name.